# How can I add a "::" operator to my VIM syntax highlighting file?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

I am using a language embedded inside of Scala that has a `::` operator. I would like to modify my scala.vim syntax file to recognize this new operator.

This is what I've tried (the first line works fine, but I don't know how to add the `::` operator to it):

```
syn match   COperator "[&|~><!)(*#%@+/=?:;}{,.\^\-\[\]]" 
syn match   COperator "\v::"
syn match   COperator "\v\:\:"
hi link COperator Special
```

Any advice?

Comment: It looks like that first line pattern will match `::` as it is. It does not limit the number of characters, so `::` will be matched by the presence of the single `:` inside the outer `[]` character class.

Comment: So, why do you want to match `::` explicitly, when you are already highlighting each `:` in it as operator, as @MichaelBerkowski pointed out?

Comment: Hmmm, "::" doesn't change colors. ":" does, ":=" does, but not "::". Does scala.vim override the pattern "::"? What does (syn match scalaOperator ":\{2,\}" "this is not a type) do? (if I comment it out, I get "::" to work, but I'm not familiar enough with regex to pinpoint "::", or Scala to know when "::" shows up).

Comment: `":\{2,\}"` Means "matching all series of `:` character if 2 or more". it will match `::` , `:::` , `::::` , `:::::` , …

Comment: Thank you.  By renaming that to `syn match COperator ":\{2,\}"`, I get "::" to syntax highlight as desired.

Comment: @Chris you should add what you did as an answer to the question and except it.

Comment: @Kazark thanks for poking me, I didn't know if that was kosher to do or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An existing `scalaOperator ":\{2,\}"` was causing all sequences of `:` to match (if there are two or more series of `:`), overriding my own `syn match COperator` statements.

The solution to get `::` to match as a `COperator` was to simply rename the scalaOperator that matches series of `:` to a COperator:

```
syn match COperator ":\{2,\}"
```

**Summary:** check for existing match rules that override your own match rules.